# SSRS - combining a lookup function AND some HTML tags inside one expression

Tags: html, reporting-services, expression, lookup

In SSRS, I am trying to use a lookup function AND some HTML tags, all within one expression.

This is my lookup function, all by itself, and it is working fine:

```
=Lookup(Fields!FUND.Value,Fields!FUND_ID.Value,Fields!CAMPAIGN_ID.Value, "DataSet2")
```

Printed: "CM"

When I add "Campaign: " to the front of that expression, it works fine also:

```
="Campaign: " + Lookup(Fields!FUND.Value,Fields!FUND_ID.Value,Fields!CAMPAIGN_ID.Value, "DataSet2")
```

Printed: "Campaign: CM"

However, when I add HTML tags, like this (extra spaces in the html tags in order to get it to print out properly here, without this form interpreting the tags and bolding this text instead of showing the tags),

```
="< b > + Campaign:  < /b >" + 
Lookup(Fields!FUND.Value,Fields!FUND_ID.Value,Fields!CAMPAIGN_ID.Value, "DataSet2")
```

the lookup function still works just fine, but SSRS doesn't recognize the HTML tags. It prints out my result like this:

"< b > Campaign: < /b > CM" (extra spaces added here also, in the html tags in order to demonstrate the problem)

Can anyone provide some advice on how to make the lookup function AND the HTML tags work at the same time?

Comment: Did set the text's placeholder properties to make sure the HTML button is checked? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ahh, yes, that is all it was. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set the text's placeholder properties to make sure the HTML button is checked.